# string variable used as column name

Tags: database

I have to use string variable as column name as follows:

```
declare
lv_emp_row emp%rowrtype;
lv_str VARCHAR2(1000);
cursor c1 is select 'ENAME' COLUMN_NAME, 'AAA' COLUMN_VALUE FROM DUAL;
begin
select * 
into lv_emp_row
from emp 
where empid=101;
lv_emp_row.empid=201;
FOR V_C1 IN C1
LOOP
  lv_str := 'lv_emp_row.'||V_C1.COLUMN_NAME || ':= '||V_C1.COLUMN_VALUE;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_str;
END LOOP;
INSERT INTO emp VALUES lv_emp_row;
end;
/
```

Why this is not working ?

Comment: can you first make it look like code? Please format it.

Comment: How is it not working? Please provide more details about your issue.

Comment: There is some problem in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_str; This EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_str part is not working. What is correct syntax for it?

Answer (score 0):

Since `lv_emp_row` is table modify your `INSERT` as below

```
INSERT INTO emp SELECT * FROM  lv_emp_row;
```